# Dependency problems with my custom build ffmpeg rpm

Tags: rpm, ffmpeg

I'm having trouble installing custom build ffmpeg 0.9.1 rpm.When I try to install ,I get the following:

> error: Failed dependencies:
>          libfaac.so.0 is needed by ffmpeg-0.9.1-1.i386
>          libmp3lame.so.0 is needed by ffmpeg-0.9.1-1.i386
>          libopencore-amrnb.so.0 is needed by ffmpeg-0.9.1-1.i386
>          libopencore-amrwb.so.0 is needed by ffmpeg-0.9.1-1.i386
>          libtheoradec.so.1 is needed by ffmpeg-0.9.1-1.i386
>          libtheoradec.so.1(libtheoradec_1.0) is needed by ffmpeg-0.9.1-1.i386
>          libtheoraenc.so.1 is needed by ffmpeg-0.9.1-1.i386
>          libtheoraenc.so.1(libtheoraenc_1.0) is needed by ffmpeg-0.9.1-1.i386
>          libvo-aacenc.so.0 is needed by ffmpeg-0.9.1-1.i386
>          libvpx.so.0 is needed by ffmpeg-0.9.1-1.i386

Yet that the dependency files are located in /usr/loca/lib.These libs are compiled and installed using gnu make.Must I intall rpm version of these libs to meet the dependency?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although these dependencies *look* like file names, they are actually 'capabilities', so having the appropriate files (i.e. shared libs) on the system will not satisfy the dependencies. You will have to install rpms. In principle, you could also install your ffmpeg rpm with `--nodeps`, but that invites trouble later on.

Answer (score 1):

I've maintained custom builds of ffmpeg for years now. The simplest way I've found to have an RPM to install is the following.

- Decide if you need to build any libs first. In some cases it may be
  advantageous to have a newer x264 or faac. Build these and create two
  RPMs, x264 and x264-devel with the dev libs.
- If the libraries from Base, Dag, or ATRPMS are good enough, install them *and*
  the matching -devel RPM too.
- Finally build ffmpeg. When you make the RPM you'll only need to
  require the running libs, not the devel libs. Test and test. It usually takes me a few tries to get the RPM right so it'll install without having to manually deal with dependencies.

I use [FPM](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) to build my RPMs.

You can of course go the --nodeps route or make an RPM with no requirements, not that I recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

Can install DAG repo 1st in you system then you can run yum install ffmpeg* -y

Comment: I've made some custom compiling options so I have to install my own version.I can compile and install from source.As there are many servers to install,I'd like to build a rpm pkg.